Signal Desktop 7.9.0 shows expired on Ubuntu 24.04?
Upon opening signal-desktop today I am presented with the message: "This version of Signal Desktop has expired. Please upgrade to the latest version to continue messaging." The message reappears if I try to send a message (and the message is not sent).
I am using Ubuntu 24.04, and the version of signal-desktop is 7.9.0. signal-desktop is installed via APT, and all packages are up-to-date.
I tried running sudo apt-get install --reinstall signal-desktop. This produces the message: "Reinstallation of signal-desktop is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.".
Has Ubuntu's APT support for Signal Desktop ended?

are any aspects in this artcle of any help?

The official Signal >> Download Signal website has instructions for installing Signal in 64-bit Debian-based
Linux distributions which you can read by clicking the blue Download for Linux button.

Install our official public software signing key:
wget -O- https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt/keys.asc | gpg --dearmor > signal-desktop-keyring.gpg
cat signal-desktop-keyring.gpg | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/signal-desktop-keyring.gpg > /dev/null


Add our repository to your list of repositories:
echo 'deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/signal-desktop-keyring.gpg] https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial main' |\
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list


Update your package database and install Signal:
sudo apt update && sudo apt install signal-desktop



In fact user643722 had already done this, so this was the problem: Somehow user643722 had signal-xenial.list.distUpgrade instead of signal-xenial.list in /etc/apt/sources.list.d directory. user643722 renamed it according to the second command in step 2., ran sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade, and then signal-desktop updated correctly.

Alternatively you can install the signal-desktop snap package in Ubuntu.
To use the Signal desktop app, you must first install Signal on your phone, then install the signal-desktop snap package with the following command:
sudo snap install signal-desktop

This installs the Signal desktop app version 7.21.0. Even though the latest version of Signal is 7.19.0, the signal-desktop snap package calls version 7.21.0 the latest/stable channel instead of version 7.19.0.
Per the request of the Signal developers, this snap does not use the system tray by default. This is disabled by default at the request of the Signal developers, because system tray support is not stable. Set to false, Signal will stop when you close it and will not have a system tray icon. You can enable it by running the following command.
snap set signal-desktop tray-icon=true


Thanks. I am aware that snap can be used. I've used it, and also built signal from source in the past. I'm interested now in continuing to use the package provided by APT. Is that possible?

@user643722 I added the instructions from the official Signal website for installing Signal with apt to the first section of my answer. It comes from a non-default (not a default Ubuntu repository) software source which is maintained by Signal developers.

In fact I had already done this, so this was my problem: somehow I had signal-xenial.list.distUpgrade instead of signal-xenial.list in my /etc/apt/sources.list.d directory. I renamed it, ran APT update/upgrade, and signal-desktop updated correctly.
